# text + variable change to number php

Tags: php

I want to create the variable like that: **"A3"**
I wrote that code:

```
$k = 1; 
print_r('A'.$k+2);
```

And the output is only "2". Why?

Comment: Why are you using print_r? Just use echo, can't delete this comment for some reason but you'd still need the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps do all arithmetic outside the print_r function.

```
$k = 1;
$r = $k + 2;
$z = 'A' . $r;
print_r($z);
```

It's only printing 2 because your arithmetic is not being executed before you print.

Comment: This answer does not explain why.

Answer (score 0):

Why this prints `2`...

```
<?php
$k = 1;
print_r('A'.$k+2);
```

There are no brackets around `($k+2)` as there should be.

So what's happening is that PHP's default [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) is used, and instead of concatenating `'A'` with `$k+2`, the `+` operator takes highest precedence.

Therefore, it's not concatenating as you expect. Instead, it's adding two values together. PHP is taking `'A'$k` and adding `2`. And because `'A'$k` as an integer, is `0`, it becomes `0+2`, giving you `2`.

To fix this, use:

```
<?php
$k = 1;
print_r('A'.($k+2));
```